# Construct an infinite matrix with finite sub-matrices

Tags: matrix

How can I construct an infinite matrix with finite sub-matrices of the form

```
A = (B0,  0, B1
      0, B2,  0
      0,  0, B3)
```

where each `Bi` is a rectangular or a square matrix?

Comment: You can't really build an "infinite" matrix, but you can build any size you want... there are some nice examples here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MatricesAndLinearAlgebra.html

Comment: @bills http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Infinite_matrices

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26250/analytically-solve-the-eigenvalue-problem-with-infinite-dimensions-by-mathematic and a [Mathematica demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheDerivativeAndTheIntegralAsInfiniteMatrices/)

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the underlying problem is. Are you trying to solve an eigenvalues problem?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica is very flexible when it comes to constructing matrices.

This below shows how to create as many tiling of matrices as you want. The tools to use are `Band` and `SparseArray` and `ConstantArray`

Starting with the 4 basic matrices `b0,b1,b2,b3`. To make the display small, small sizes will be used.

```
b0 = N@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
b1 = N@{{5, 6}, {7, 8}};
b2 = N@{{9, 10}, {11, 12}};
b3 = N@{{13, 14}, {15, 16}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the first iteration is build

```
s = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> ConstantArray[b0, 1], 
    Band[{3, 3}] -> ConstantArray[b2, 1], 
    Band[{5, 5}] -> ConstantArray[b3, 1], 
    Band[{1, 5}] -> ConstantArray[b1, 1]}];
MatrixForm[s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now using the above, it is in turn is used to build another iteration. Here it is used on the diagonal only, but using Band you can put it in any other location

```
s2 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> ConstantArray[s, 3]];
MatrixForm[s2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The processes can continue as much as you need

Comment: you could also use `ArrayFlatten` like in `ArrayFlatten[{{b0, 0, b1} , {0, b2, 0}, {0, 0, b3}}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: ...and following up on user21's suggestion, use `KroneckerProduct[]` to construct the larger matrix: `KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[3], ArrayFlatten[{{b0, 0, b1}, {0, b2, 0}, {0, 0, b3}}]]`